# Parsing SQL file with Python

Tags: python, sql

I'm trying to parse a SQL code and extract all the table names from it.

The table names in the sql code are sometimes written with alias or schema.table or only table name.

I'm using **sqlparse** package but I'm only getting the alias of the tables, you will find my code bellow :

```
SELECT  *
FROM VA_ASSISTES va, datamart_Sales.dbo.Seller f,
datamart_Sales.dbo.ARTICLES a, SITE s, datamart_Sales.dbo.TEMPS t
```

This is what I get now as a result, only the alias :

**Tables: va, f, a, s, t**

However, I want to retrieve the table name  like this :
**datamart_Sales.dbo.Seller , datamart_Sales.dbo.ARTICLES, datamart_Sales.dbo.TEMPS, SITE**

I will really appreciate it if someone can help me to extract the table name in all the cases mentions above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sqlparse` does not specifically label `identifier`s as belonging to column names/aliases, or table names/aliases. Thus, you will have to loop over the parsed tokens and mark when a `from` keyword occurs, and then retain subsequent `identifiers`:

```
import sqlparse
s = """SELECT  *
FROM VA_ASSISTES va, datamart_Sales.dbo.Seller f,
datamart_Sales.dbo.ARTICLES a, SITE s, datamart_Sales.dbo.TEMPS t"""
s1="""SELECT job_id,AVG(salary) FROM VA_ASSISTES va, datamart_Sales.dbo.Seller f, datamart_Sales.dbo.ARTICLES a, SITE s, datamart_Sales.dbo.TEMPS t Havning job_id,AVG(salary)< (SELECT MAX(AVG(min_salary)) FROM jobs WHERE job_id IN (SELECT job_id FROM job_history WHERE department_id BETWEEN 50 AND 100) GROUP BY job_id));"""
def get_tables(p):
   f = False
   for i in p:
      if i.value.lower() == 'from':
         f = True
      if f and isinstance(i, (sqlparse.sql.Identifier, sqlparse.sql.IdentifierList)):
         if isinstance(i, sqlparse.sql.IdentifierList):
            yield from [j.value.split() for j in i.get_identifiers()]
         else:
             yield i.value.split()
         f = False
      yield from get_tables(getattr(i, '__iter__', lambda :[])())

print(list(get_tables(sqlparse.parse(s)[0])))
print(list(get_tables(sqlparse.parse(s1)[0])))
```

Output:

```
[['VA_ASSISTES', 'va'], ['datamart_Sales.dbo.Seller', 'f'], ['datamart_Sales.dbo.ARTICLES', 'a'], ['SITE', 's'], ['datamart_Sales.dbo.TEMPS', 't']]
[['VA_ASSISTES', 'va'], ['datamart_Sales.dbo.Seller', 'f'], ['datamart_Sales.dbo.ARTICLES', 'a'], ['SITE', 's'], ['datamart_Sales.dbo.TEMPS', 't'], ['jobs'], ['job_history']]
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompte reply!
How about if I have nested  queries like this : 

SELECT  job_id,AVG(salary) 
FROM VA_ASSISTES va, datamart_Sales.dbo.Seller f,
datamart_Sales.dbo.ARTICLES a, SITE s, datamart_Sales.dbo.TEMPS t
Havning job_id,AVG(salary)< SELECT MAX(AVG(min_salary))            
FROM jobs             
WHERE job_id IN                 
(SELECT job_id FROM job_history                  
WHERE department_id                   
BETWEEN 50 AND 100)             
GROUP BY job_id);

Comment: @Abdelhak You will need to use recursion. Please see my recent edit.